# What is the right way to say "I've heard recommendations about you"

Tags: prepositions

I am going to write to one person on LinkedIn (to/on/about/for?) whom I've got recommendations from my ex. colleague and I'd like to refer to that.

I'd like to say something in a sense: "Hello I've heard Peters recommendations on you so I have decided to..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two proposals:

"Hello,

 Peter spoke highly of you, so I have decided to contact you..."

"Hello,

On the advice/recommendation of Peter, I have decided to contact you ..."

The first message is a bit warmer than the second one.

Comment: Thank you. It has solved my problem, but I still wonder how should a word "recommendations" be used in case I wanted to go with something more similar to what I've offered.

Comment: To stick with your first idea, I would say :

 "Hello, I have received Peter's recommendation about you // of your profile".   I feel it's a bit heavier than what I suggested in the answer, but it would be gramatically correct.